# How to Create a Token on several blockchains?

Tags: solidity

How can i create a token on several blockchains like Ethereum and binance smart chain?
Should i create 2 apart contract ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the development frameworks, you can just deploy the same smart contract to the two networks and the framework will keep track of the address for each of the network. Just add the network to your config file and then call the deploy script using `--network` flag.

As for the naming of the tokens, it comes down to the use case. You have to decide if you are having both smart contracts use the same name or if you want some differentiation per network.